# Getting java.lang.VerifyError on access of Singleton class Android Amazon Appstore

Tags: android, singleton, verifyerror

I created an App for Android and it is running on android market successfully. Now I am trying to get it live on Amazon App store so I submitted my app to amazon and they start reviewing it. And after some time they said that your app is crashing at a specific point 5 out of 5 times.

Here is the crash report:

```
11-16 17:47:49.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9627): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-16 17:47:49.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9627): java.lang.VerifyError: [package_name].manager.DestinationViewManger
11-16 17:47:49.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9627):  at [package_name].activity.SearchScreenActivity.performClickFunctionality(SearchScreenActivity.java)
11-16 17:47:49.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9627):  at [package_name].activity.SearchScreenActivity.access$0(SearchScreenActivity.java)
11-16 17:47:49.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9627):  at [package_name].activity.SearchScreenActivity$1.onClick(SearchScreenActivity.java)
11-16 17:47:49.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9627):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2532)
11-16 17:47:49.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9627):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9277)
11-16 17:47:49.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9627):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-16 17:47:49.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9627):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-16 17:47:49.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9627):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
11-16 17:47:49.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9627):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4196)
11-16 17:47:49.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9627):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-16 17:47:49.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9627):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-16 17:47:49.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9627):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-16 17:47:49.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9627):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-16 17:47:49.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9627):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-16 17:47:49.470: W/ActivityManager(1419):   Force finishing activity [package_name]/.activity.HomeScreenRepairActivity
```

From this crash log I am sure there will be a problem with DestinationViewManger class and unable to solve that crash.

This is code written in the `DestinationViewManager` class:

```
public class DestinationViewManger {
    
    private static DestinationViewManger instance = null;
    private Boolean flag;
     
    private DestinationViewManger(){
        
    }
    
    public static DestinationViewManger getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new DestinationViewManger();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public Boolean getFlag() {
        return flag;
    }

    public void setFlag(Boolean flag) {
        this.flag = flag;
    }
    
}
```

Earlier the crash was not coming at my end but finally I found the crash on the binary that is given by the amazon-appstore team. Actually there is a 3 step process at amazon-appstore to upload the .apk file (I hope anybody know about this).

These steps are:

1. upload unsigned binary then,
2. download the processed binary from amazon and then,
3. upload the signed binary.

Now when I install the signed .apk file, that I uploaded in step 3, on my phone it crashes. And if I sign binary that I uploaded in step 1 then it does not crashes.

Does anyone know why is this crash coming?

Is this crash occurring due to the processing of binary done by amazon-appstore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had removed crash by changing the package name its crazy but it worked for me. Earlier the package name was [application_package_name].manager and i think amazon people also doing something with the same package name. So when i just randomly doing something to remove the crash and accidently changed the package name from manager to [application_package_name].searchmanager and it start working. And i was yepeeee....

Comment: I had the same issue, had a package named util which was causing VerifyError on Amazon AppStore, renamed it to utils, problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

```
public class DestinationViewManger {

    private static final DestinationViewManger instance = new DestinationViewManger();
    public Boolean flag=false;

 // Private constructor prevents instantiation from other classes
    private DestinationViewManger(){   }

    public static DestinationViewManger getInstance() {
        return instance;
    } 
}
```

//try this singleton class once. no need for getter and setter method

```
DestinationViewManger dstv;

dstv=DestinationViewManger.getInstance();

dstv.flag=true; //set the value for your flag

boolean whatFlagboo=dstv.flag; //get your flag wherever you want
```

Comment: Thanks @Padma Kumar for the quick response. But calling constructor at the declaration and not in the static method make any difference??

Comment: Actually i didn't noticed that you have changed the access modifier of flag. Yes you are right we don't need getter and setter for public variables.

Comment: I want to know that what is the problem in my code that you have solved in your code?

Comment: notting :-) . I thing your singleton class is ok. I guess problem in your HomeScreenRepairActivity.

Comment: DestinationViewManager is being accessed by the SearchScreenActivity and not by the HomeScreenRepairActivity so their can not be the problem.